# Long pause after mapping backslash to `gt`?

Tags: vim, neovim, backslash

In my current workflow I use tabs quite a bit, and always end up either typing `gtgtgtgt` in quick succession or `4gt` to skip to the 4th tab.

This seems unnecessary, so I mapped my backslash key to act like `gt`, i.e. `4<Bslash>` that skips to the 4th tab:

```
map <Bslash> gt
```

However when I use it there's a long pause before it actually goes and flips to that tab. Anything I can do to accelerate it?

Comment: There is a setting you can use to control how long `vim` waits for the next keystroke. The most immediate problem, I think, is that the key you chose is the default mapleader, which means `vim` *expects* another key to appear after the backslash. (See `:help <leader>` for more information.

Comment: I do have `let mapleader=","` earlier in my rcfile. Does that not leave backslash to act like a "regular" key? 

Comment: Can you add your full `vimrc` to your question?